# Jupyter on mac complains "No module named pandas"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

Here are the steps that I did:

1. I installed anaconda on my mac.
2. I created a new environment using `conda create -n myenv`
3. I activated this environment using `conda activate myenv`
4. I installed several modules including pandas
5. I run `conda list` and it showed `pandas                    1.1.5            py38hb2f4e1b_0`
6. I launched jupyter from anaconda dashboard
7. In the `new notebook`, I can see my new environment `myenv`, so I created a new notebook using  `myenv`
8. In the notebook, I run this code `import pandas as pd` and it throws me this error:

   ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
    in ()
   1 import numpy as np
   ----> 2 import pandas as pd

   ImportError: No module named pandas
9. I checked anaconda dashboard environment then check the installed modules under `myenv` and `pandas` is there.  So i'm wondering why it cannot find the module.
10. I tried running `!pip install pandas --upgrade` in my opened `myenv` notebook and it showed this results

```
Installing collected packages: pandas
  Attempting uninstall: pandas
    Found existing installation: pandas 1.1.3
    Uninstalling pandas-1.1.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pandas-1.1.3
Successfully installed pandas-1.1.5
```

Now I'm lost why it upgraded the pandas from 1.1.3 to 1.1.5 while the version of pandas in `myenv` environment is already 1.1.5

How can I get `pandas` to run in my environment correctly?

Comment: can you give the output of `sys.path` from your notebook? do you have multiple python versions?

Comment: You should be using `conda install pandas` rather than pip

Comment: i run sys.path in the notebook and the path still won't point to my conda myenv path
it says...
`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7`

but in the terminal, when i run `conda activate myenv` then run sys.path in python prompt, it shows...
`.../opt/anaconda3/envs/ml-101/lib/python3.8`.. i thought if i create a notebook using `myenv`, it will use the modules on that environment

Answer (score 1):

Try to use it in Notebook. It will help you to know if you're using the correct env(python) or your default system installed python.

```
**!which python**
**!pip freeze**
```

Most probably you'll find out that you're using system python
then try to run this command on the terminal after activating your env.

```
**python -m ipykernel install --user --name=YourEnvName**(or any Name)
```

and you'll definitely see a new kernel in your notebook by the name "YourEnvName"
[Check the image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IhCN.png)

Thanks!!